# Why ui-view isn't displayed after reloading?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I click on link with sref or change state using $state.go template in ui-view change properly but when I press f5 to reload page or type address in addres line template in ui-view disappears. Why and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I was calling $rootScope.$apply() when page was loading. It was mistake. Be careful.